# how to get live loccation using GeoQuery method in android firebase realtimeDatabase?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, geolocation, latitude-longitude

How to get current Live Location using GeoQuery Method from Firebase RealTime Database. Is working GeoQuery in Android Version 9.0 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Locations that are stored in the database are not necessarily related to the current location of the user/device.

To get the latter, you'll want to look at the Android APIs to get a location, for example this documentation on [getting the last known location](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current) and [How do I get the current GPS location programmatically in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513485/how-do-i-get-the-current-gps-location-programmatically-in-android)